# Why C# singleton class sometimes calls two method in multi threading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, singleton

I am having issue with my singleton class in multi threading environment. This sample program calls method A & B on separate threads. Normally this works ok.

In some cases as shown in the last result at bottom

- method A call starts
- method B call starts
- method B call ends
- then method A call ends<---- why is this happening out of order ?

Is this because I am not performing double lock ? 
How do I ensure that this does not happen ?

Caller

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(CallonThread));
            Singleton.Instance.Test("B");
            Console.ReadKey();

    }

    static void CallonThread(object a)
    {
        Singleton.Instance.Test("A");
    }
}
```

Singleton Class

```
public class Singleton
{
    static readonly object Padlock = new object();
    private static Singleton _instance;
    protected Singleton()
    {
    }
    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (Padlock)
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new Singleton();
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }
    }
    public void Test(string id)
    {
        if (id == "A")
        {
            new Data().MethodA();
        }
        else
        {
            new Data().MethodB();
        }
    }
}
```

Data class

```
public class Data
{
    public void MethodA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start Method A");
        Console.WriteLine("End Method A");
    }
    public void MethodB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start Method B");
        Console.WriteLine("End Method B");
    }
}
```

Result
[image]

Comment: This is just multi-threading doing it's thing, there is no locking in the methods.

Comment: If you don't want this to happen, don't execute multiple threads.

Comment: And I assume you meant "then method A call **ends**" in your question, since that's what your screenshot shows?

Comment: @Blorgbeard yes, fixed the typo. But this method in production can get called from multi threading classes

Comment: @tkausl where would I put lock to not let this happen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work to stop MethodA and MethodB from executing simultaneously:

```
public class Data
{

    private static object _padlock = new object();

    public void MethodA()
    {
        lock (_padlock)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start Method A");
            Console.WriteLine("End Method A");
        }
    }
    public void MethodB()
    {
        lock (_padlock)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start Method B");
            Console.WriteLine("End Method B");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right so this happens due to singleton being called from different threads ? If I make it non singleton then it would work as expected because it will have two different instance..right ?

Comment: No, both instances would still be writing to the same shared resource (the console). In fact, you already create separate instances of `Data`. That doesn't stop code running in parallel.

Comment: Presumably, your real code does something more useful than writing to the console. The best way to make code thread-safe is to give each thread its own instance, and have no shared resources between instances. If you can do that, then you don't need locks.

Comment: yes the real code is a library used inside a web application. I can't stop the threading from happening and singleton class was created to restrict the access to data class from only one access point. In this case I need to make sure all my code has appropriate lock and need to make sure it does not create overhead in performance due to many locks

Comment: Hi I tried thi solution in prod code but I still see more threads starting the same method even with static object lock. i verified that there is only one instance but when lots of thread suddenly come in, they access method at the same time even with lock

Comment: What do you mean by "access method"? multiple threads can enter the method, but all but one of them (at a time) will stop at the lock statement.

Comment: So it works as you described when we have only few threads like 10-20 but but as we increase the number of threads...I see the same issue as shown in my screen shot.

Comment: I can't see how that would be the case given your code - of course, the code here is not your real code. I suggest you try to construct a compilable, runnable example of reasonable size that reproduces your problem. Then post a new question with it.